# X server fails to start after NVIDIA driver update

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, xorg

I have made the mistake of trying to install an NVIDIA driver from a .run file on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. 
Ever since I have been stuck in a low graphics mode, unable to get the login screen booted properly. 
I am only able to turn on the non-graphical interface (ctrl + alt + F2) and run startx after login, 
which brings me into a blank screen with unity background and a cross instead of mouse pointer 
(I can start a terminal through right click but no panels or anything).

If I go to *failsafex* in recovery mode, I get the "no screens found" error (see the attached Xorg.failsafe log).
I have gone through most of the related forum topics and tried the following:

- purge remove *nvidia
- reinstalling ubuntu-desktop
- reinstalling, reconfiguring and restarting lightdm
- reinstalling, reconfiguring and restarting xserver-xorg
- removing the whole /.config folder (I have a backup)
- reinstalling compiz
- using nomodeset to boot my kernel - this has no result except I cannot even start the X server then
- again installing nvidia-current and an nvidia-driver through apt get
- deleting the .Xauthority file
- apt-get update, upgrade and reboot after each step

Unfortunately none of these helped. I have also tried to boot into previous kernels, but the situation is the same for all of them. 
My current kernel is 4.15.0-54. I am not an experienced user, so I might have messed it up by deleting some files I shouldn't.
At the moment I have the nvidia-current package installed along with the nvidia-304 driver (I have a GeForce GTX1060).
Thank you for any help.

Also deep apologies for attaching the log as image, but I kept getting "this looks like spam" when I added it as text (though with code formatting).

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crnxC.png)